# Windows 8 + VS11 doesn't work?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-8

I've downloaded the W8 Developer Preview, installed VS11 Ultimate on it, and I get errors when I try to build the applications.
My W8 copy has something wrong with a character set, and I'm unable to read what the errors are.

Comment: You really don't give enough detail for anyone being able to help you.

Comment: Why not just use the Windows 8 image that comes with the dev tools preinstalled? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/br229516

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem, but I actually received error messages about makepri.exe. In the msdn forums they said I should have installed the iso with visual studio included to be able to build metro applications. Then google-translated this site http://www.umutcankoseali.com/?p=338, followed the instructions, and it fixed.